# Is a dynamic stylesheet solution to view secondary single page on wordpress with multiple themes?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am using the same theme as these sites, but I use two themes on my site compared to these.

1. http://marioortega.net/
2. http://atelier6.co.uk/

When you click one of the thumbnails, the single ends up on top and the thumbnails at the bottom.

How do I make the site below do that without affecting the base theme?  Currently, when I click the thumbnails, it goes to the base theme single entry view.

Comment: This question is probably better asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Should use

```
<?php if (is_category('category-test')) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style-green.css" />
<?php } ?>
```